# crdb_oracle.dll could not be loaded in Crystal Reports 2008

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports, report

I have installed crystal reports studio 2008 on win server 2012. when i try to run a report in crystal, i get following error:

**The database connector crdb_oracle.dll could not be loaded. The correct version of the database client for this database type might not be installed.**

I don't even see Oracle in the list of possible data sources in crystal reports. And Oracle driver was selected during crystal reports installation.

Oracle 11.2.0 client is installed. TNSping is working, all DLL's are in place. The same set of products (except on win-7 x86) is working just fine, so oracle and crystal should match.

Please see attahced screens. Advices i found on the Internet didn't help at all. Please advise.

[screens-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoBte.png)

[screens-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yii7a.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have figured out what was the issue.
As CrystalReports was 32-bit app, and windows server was 64-bit, i was missing 32-bit oracle client (just 64-bit version was installed). After i have installed 32-but oracle client, crystal worked fine.